# Swift Navigation Title Bar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in swift development. I have deleted the main storyboard because I wanted to try develop everything programmatically. I wanted to add the navigation bar with title. Any suggestion:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.backgroundColor = .white
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setTitle("Random Photo", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed,
        .systemBlue,
        .systemCyan,
        .systemGray,
        .systemIndigo
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y:0,
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        )
        imageView.center = view.center
        
        view.addSubview(button)
        getRandomPhoto()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func didTapButton(){
        getRandomPhoto()
        
        view.backgroundColor = colors.randomElement()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        button.frame = CGRect(
            x:30,
            y:view.frame.size.height-150-view.safeAreaInsets.bottom,
            width: view.frame.size.width-60,
            height: 55
        )
        
    }
    
    func getRandomPhoto(){
        let urlString = "https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            return
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
```

- I already tried this but it does not appear any title. Any help to appear the navigation title bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the navigation title bar programmatically:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   setNavigationTitleBar()
}

func setNavigationTitleBar() {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: screenSize.width, height: 80))
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Navigation Title Bar")
    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
    self.view.addSubview(navBar)
}
```

Kindly prefer the above code snippet for set the navigation title bar programmatically.

Comment: Nice, it's work nicely but it does not cover all until top, may I know how I can control it

Comment: Yes, By changing the value of y:50 to y:0 and then it working fine.